# How to find out what makes gradle slow when not in offline mode

Tags: java, gradle, build

My build usually runs for 10 seconds when every project is up to date. But today every project takes on average about 40 sec to complete. When I turn the --offline mode on, it runs fast again. There is has to be something that slows it down - something related to trying to communicate with some external resources. Is there a way to figure out what causes the slow down? My gradle version is 2.14.1

UPDATE: Here is the build scan:

https://scans.gradle.com/s/mzqnuvgjtve76/tasks

Comment: It's checking to see if there are newer versions of your dependencies available.

Comment: If so how would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to get an idea about what's slow in your build is to execute the project with the [Build Scan capability](https://scans.gradle.com/get-started?type=project) enabled. The Build Scan will give you a break down on where the time is spent. If you post the link to your Build Scan we can further analyze your issue.

Comment: I tried build scan it told me that dependencies took 27min out of 28min of the whole build. And Now I can't test it anymore because its fast again.

Comment: Can you provide us with the link to the build scan so we can have a look? BTW: Are you using a lot of `SNAPSHOT`/changing dependencies and/or dynamic dependencies e.g. `1.+` or `latest.release`?

Comment: I added the link. We used to use axis2 SNAPSHOT and now using the  release version

Comment: Thanks for providing the link to the build scan. Changing the Axis2 dependency to a release version should help. Looking at the high number may indicate that you don't have a local cache available for your dependencies. Are you potentially deleting the Gradle cache after every build which triggered a new download? Are you sharing the Gradle cache  across builds when run on CI? Do you have a very slow network?

Comment: It was never happening before. It only started to happen now and even now some days its ok and some other days its slow. And I dont delete my cache at all.

Comment: Did you change any of your Gradle configuration recently? BTW: I'd also try to run your build with the latest Gradle version, with `--parallel` and `--configure-on-demand`. You can find more information on how to improve performance in the [Gradle performance guide](http://gradle.github.io/performance-guide/).

Comment: It's not necessarily I want to improve performance. I just want to figure out what makes it  occasionally extremely slow. The problem appears and goes away without any changes to the configuration.

Comment: Do you see that the dependencies are downloaded again? If yes, then something is missing with your local Gradle cache.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue now - it works fine now. Even when it was slow I did not see anything downloading from maven.

Comment: I'd need to see your build configuration then. It's hard to diagnose what's going on without any insight. I suggest you ask the question on the [Gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/) instead.

Comment: Ok I will try to do this